# Add dot on canvas grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a canvas grid with the coordinates labelled when you click on the grid at [here](https://codepen.io/tealynsea/pen/Eavzpb) May I ask how to place a red dot on the grid as shown in the picture? Please provide a demo for understanding:)

[image]

[image]

```
function showCoords(event) {
    var x = event.clientX - 10;
    var y = event.clientY - 10;
    var coords = "X coordinates: " + x + ", Y coordinates: " + y;
    document.getElementById('showCoords').innerHTML = coords;

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so first you may create a CSS class for the red dots:

```
  <style>
    .red-dot {
      position:absolute; 
      width:5px; 
      height:5px;
      background:red;
    }
  </style>
```

Then try to modify the `showCoords()` method:

```
function showCoords(event) {
    // Calculate the position of the nearest grid intersection:
    var x = (Math.floor(event.clientX/10) * 10) - 2;
    var y = (Math.floor(event.clientY/10) * 10) - 2;
    var coords = "X coordinates: " + x + ", Y coordinates: " + y;
    document.getElementById('showCoords').innerHTML = coords;
    // Create a new red dot:
    let newDot = document.createElement('span');
    // Add the CSS class:
    newDot.className = 'red-dot';
    // Set coordinates:
    newDot.style.top = y + 'px';
    newDot.style.left = x + 'px';
    // Add the new element to the end of the body:
    document.body.appendChild(newDot);
  }
```

Comment: Hi sir, I have followed your code at updated it at https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/NWXvVEm?editors=0010     , I have added a click me button at the bottom to delete all the red dots drawn before and tried newDot.className.remove(); . May I know how to remove the classname so that all the red dots get deleted? :)

Comment: Here is one of the ways to do it: `let paras = document.getElementsByClassName('red-dot');
while(paras[0]) {
    paras[0].parentNode.removeChild(paras[0]);
}`

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for your guidance :)However, if you scroll down to the Click ME button and try to place a red dot on the canvas, the cursor you click will place the red dot in another direction. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: It's because `clientY` is relative to the browser window. Try using `event.pageY` instead of `event.clientY`. You should do the same with the X axis if you expect a scroll there.